# Running subprocess on linux server doesn't work but works locally on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Running subprocess works locally on Windows but does not work when I add the script on the linux box and run it. A subprocess object does get created but it just hangs and waits there.

This is the script I am running:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["php", "random.php", username, password], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

p.wait()
```

I've looked at php ini, disabled functions and it's empty. I've tried to add a `a = p.communicate()` and `print a` but this doesn't print anything

I'm running out of things I can do, is there anything else I can do to debug why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: one way to debug would be to try to read `p.stdout` (standard output), and check return code returned by `p.wait()`. Also, try to get rid of `shell=True` if possible (try `where php` on windows and `which php` on Linux, those may be 2 different object types (.bat/.exe...)

Comment: Try using `communicate`.... [The docs say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) `Warning: This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE ....` and suggest using `communicate` to avoid this problem.

Comment: @sytech the deadlock is when redirecting both stdout and stderr to `PIPE` and not using `communicate`. Oh but you're right (and I'm not suggesting otherwise: if you redirect, _read_ the output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good lead would be that the process blocks because you're using redirection, but not consuming the output. Depending on the operating system and buffer sizes, this may or may not work.

If the process ends without outputting too much so the output pipe doesn't fill up, it'll work, else it'll block.

It seems that you don't want the output, you just want to make the process quiet. In that case, *do not* redirect with `subprocess.PIPE`

Python 3 has `subprocess.DEVNULL`

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["php", "random.php", username, password], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Python 2 hasn't, but you can fake it

```
with open(os.devnull,"w") as f:
   p = subprocess.Popen(["php", "random.php", username, password], stdout=f, stderr=f)
```

then:

```
rc =p.wait()
```

and *check return code*